# How long can motion tracking work?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to know how long can a tango's motion tracking can go ?

How is it calculated ?

for example it can track for 10 minutes or it can track for 1 km or it can track till 1 million points. Its there any measurement parameter to calculate limits ?

Note I don't have the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a parameter or calculation that defines how long a Tango can do motion tracking, but my guess would be that it can do it until the battery dies or the memory runs out.

However, I wouldn't consider the time or tracking limits as main concerns with motion tracking; rather, the *accuracy* of the tracking will lower with excessive movement and the longer the tracking runs due to drifting caused by accumulating sensor errors. This is corrected to a large degree with the Tango's area learning mechanism, but just how long or over what distance the error will start to play a significant role will depend on a number of different factors.

Comment: sounds reasonable ...let wait a little more before accepting answer . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, Motion Tracking could run as long as the device still has battery.

Motion Tracking takes only a single frame image and discard it after pose estimation. Unlike Area Learning, it doesn't store any information on disk. Thus, memory-wise, it has no limitation.

However, as Yassie said, Motion Tracking does drift over time. It's related to distance that device has traveled, and the amount is roughly 10% of travel distance. Area Learning is good way of reducing that.

Also, thermal plays a role in this as well. You will see performance degrading when device gets really hot. This is common to all applications (not only Tango). But if application load is not super heavy and the heat dissipation is good on the device, it still can run as long as you want.